# What does a numpy shape starting with zero mean

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Okay, so I found out that you can have arrays with 0s in their shape.
For the case where you have 0 as the only dimension, this makes sense to me. It is an empty array.

```
np.zeros(0)
```

But the case where you have something like this:

```
np.zeros((0, 100))
```

Is confusing for me. Why is it defined like this?

Comment: It's just saying for the first dimension you have zero elements... and the second dimension you have 100 elements... but because you have zero elements in the first dimension essentially there's no second dimension.

Comment: Without context, it's impossible to tell. It could be, for example, a sentence vector, where each word has 100 features; but the sentence is empty (contains no words). Could be a measurement of temperature, where you take measurement every day at 100 locations, but you just started and it's your first day and you haven't measured anything yet. You haven't supplied any code for us to see beyond that one line, so... it's anyone's guess, really.

Comment: @Amadan So it is just additional info for a blank array?

Comment: That means you have "0 rows and 100 columns", and the total number of elements is 0 * 100 = 0. It is not very useful per se, but allowing for these shapes makes easier to write consistent code for corner cases. For example, if you have an array `a` with shape `(10, 100)` and do `np.sum(a[:idx], axis=0)`, the result will be correct even if `idx` is 0 (in which case it would result in a 100-vector of zeros).

Comment: Again, no idea. Post context, then we can talk. :P

Comment: @Amadan Well, I discovered this by accident. But I was preprocessing strings into their one-hot encodings and accidentally supplied an empty string.

Comment: `numpy` arrays are defined not just by their data elements, but also by their `shape`.  `shape` is expressed as a `tuple` - up to 32 non-negative numbers.  We seldom need to create an array with a 0 dimension, but we need to be comfortable with the concept.  `numpy` does not have an explicit concept or definition of an `empty` array.  That's something we bring in from outside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know it's just a redundant way to express an empty array. It doesn't seems to matter for python if you have rows of "emptiness".

Let's say we have a give array a:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((0,100))
```

If we print a all we get is the empty array itself:

```
print(a)

>>> []
```

Moreover we can actually see that despite this a maintain it's shape"

```
np.shape(a)

>>> (0, 100)
```

But if you try to access a given element by position, e.g:

```
print(a[0])
```

or

```
print(a[0][0])
```

You get an IndexError :

```
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

Therefore I believe that the mathematical meaning of the empty arrays, despite the shape you assign to them, is the same.

Answer (score 0):

It is an empty array that is supposed to be filled in the near future, so the idea is to give your intention of its use.
If your use for this array is to store 10 values that represent some metric, you define it as:

```
np.zeros((0, 10))
```

instead of empty dimensions with a comment (which are more vulnerable):

```
np.zeros(0) # This will store 10 values
```

So at the end of the day, the point is just to make your code more readable with clear intentions for the reader that can your future self.

Answer (score -1):

Well, in this particular case, the two statements are equivilant:

```
print(np.zeros(0))
>>>[]

print(np.zeros((0,100)))
>>>[]
```

This is because an empty array is an empty array.  Your intuitions are correct there.  If you put in:

```
np.zeros(10)
```

or

```
np.zeros((1,10))
```

you'd also get the same array, namely `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`.  The shape only matters when you are referring to a number that actually changes the shape of the array.  For instance:

```
print(np.zeros((2,3)))
>>>[[0,0,0]
   [0,0,0]]
```

but:

```
print(np.zeros((3,2)))
>>>[[0,0]
    [0,0]
    [0,0]]
```

Nothing particularly opaque about it.  Your common sense actually applies here.  If an array is empty, none of the other dimensions you add to it matter.

Comment: Those two statements are not the same.  Yes, they both produce an array with 0 elements, but their shapes are different.  In the second set, both have 10 elements, but again shapes differ.  Shape does matter, for example in how arrays interact with other arrays.

Comment: Hence why I used the qualifyer "in this particular case"  The confusion was this:

"For the case where you have 0 as the only dimension, this makes sense to me. It is an empty array."

I was simply pointing out that, in reference to this question, the two statements mean the same thing.  They are both empty arrays.  The shapes are different but if you want to index the array then any empty array will be the same.  There was confusion concerning whether the second statement was, in fact, an empty array.  I was merely explaining that it, like the first one, is.